# Python import other file variable that triggers a function that returns variable

Tags: python, python-import, getter-setter

Okay so the issue is that I need to import a variable that needs to trigger a function to check if a file exists and if not, download the file and set the variable. I would normally get this functionality from a class with getters and setters but since I don't want my user to have to set the variable for the class this brings up an interesting problem.

So this works but does not have the functionality needed:

**Run.py File:**

```
from examples.mnist import images, labels, show

print(images)
print(labels)

show()
```

**MNIST File:**

```
images = "Images goes here"
labels = "Labels go here"

def show():
    print("Im showing your image")
```

So to put it simply. How do I import a variable that will have a getter/setter function without making the user set the object/class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a module-level `__getattr__`, as specified by [PEP 562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/):

```
# mnist.py
def __getattr__(name):
    if name=='images':
        if not file_exist_check():
            download_file()
        return read_file()
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__} has no attribute {name}")
```